# Mismatched delete when freeing 2D array

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor

I've been staring into this for a while now and I don't see why it should fail. I have a CMatrix class, implementing a 2D matrix, like this:

```
class CMatrix {
public:
    CMatrix(int height, int width);
    ~CMatrix();
    // more stuff here
private:
    void deleteData();
    void allocData(int height, int width);

    int rows, cols;
    double** data;
};

CMatrix::CMatrix(int height, int width) {
    allocData(height, width);
}

CMatrix::~CMatrix() {
    deleteData();
}
```

it works fine, until I try to destroy it. There are two methods responsible for allocation and deallocation, defined as follows:

```
void CMatrix::allocData(int height, int width) {
    this->rows = height;
    this->cols = width;

    data = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        data[i] = new double[cols];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            data[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

void CMatrix::deleteData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
}
```

This simple `main` code causes it to malfunction:

```
int main(int argc, char** 

    CMatrix a(2, 3);
    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 2;
    a[0][2] = 3;
    a[1][0] = 4;
    a[1][1] = 5;
    a[1][2] = 6;

    return 0;
}
```

valgrind says this:

```
==21005== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==21005==    at 0x4C2A44B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21005==    by 0x402B5C: CMatrix::deleteData() (main.cpp:375)
==21005==    by 0x401731: CMatrix::~CMatrix() (main.cpp:138)
==21005==    by 0x402F5D: main (main.cpp:598)
==21005==  Address 0x5a06090 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 alloc'd
==21005==    at 0x4C2AAA4: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21005==    by 0x402A84: CMatrix::allocData(int, int) (main.cpp:366)
==21005==    by 0x4015FB: CMatrix::CMatrix(int, int) (main.cpp:123)
==21005==    by 0x402D63: main (main.cpp:415)
```

This message gets printed when in method `deleteData()` and `i=0`. It doesn't say anything for other `i`s, nor for delete[].

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `delete[]` on each of your rows because they were allocated with `new[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    delete[] data[i];
}
```

Note that the `[i]` at the end is an array subscript, and has nothing to do with `delete[]`. Think of it like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    double* p = data[i];
    delete[] p;
}
```

Since `p` points at the first element in a dynamically allocated array, it must be `delete[]`ed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer that identified `delete[]` vs. `delete` issue, note that you should also define a *copy constructor* and *`operator=`* for your `CMatrix` class (or declare them `private` to ban copy semantics), since you are directly managing raw resources (i.e. dynamically allocated memory) in your class.
See the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for more details.

Or you can simply use a *direct resource manager* like `std::vector`, instead of allocating memory with `new[]`. You can also define nested vectors to build a 2D matrix, like in `vector<vector<double>>`. In this way, `std::vector` will properly do memory allocation, cleanup, and copy automatically.

Comment: I actually have these in my code (along with +,-,* etc), they just weren't relevant so I omitted them in order to minimalize the question  length. You are right, though. Vector is forbidden in this particular case, as this is a part of school work I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

Your delete function doesn't delete the memory block you allocated for colums in each rows

Code should be like this

```
void CMatrix::deleteData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    delete [] data;
}
```